# How to pull all photograph rows that relate to at least all three of the searched tags

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: photographs, and photograph_tags.  Photograph_tags contains a column called photograph_id (id in photographs).  You can have many tags for one photograph. I have a photograph row related to three tags: boy, stream, and water. However, running the following query returns 0 rows

```
SELECT p.*
FROM photographs p, photograph_tags c
WHERE c.photograph_id = p.id
AND (c.value IN ('dog', 'water', 'stream'))
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT( p.id )=3
```

My tables look like so

```
-----------------------
photographs
-----------------------
id | title | location
------------------------
7  | asdf | c:\...


-----------------------
photograph_tags
-----------------------
id | photograph_id | value
1  | 7             | dog
2  | 7             | water
3  | 7             | stream
4  | 7             | mountains
```

Why is my query not giving me my desired results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get all photos with the 3 tags (OR MORE) you specified. Start with the Tags and join the photos.

```
select
 p.id
from photographs p

left join photograph_tags c
on p.id = c.photograph_id
and c.value IN ('dog', 'water', 'stream')

group by p.id

having count(c.value) >= 3
```

testing the above code:

```
create table #photograph_tags (
    photograph_id INT,
    value varchar(50)
)

create table #photographs (
    id int
)

insert into #photographs values (7)
insert into #photographs values (8)

insert into #photograph_tags values (7, 'dog')
insert into #photograph_tags values (7, 'water')
insert into #photograph_tags values (7, 'stream')
insert into #photograph_tags values (7, 'mountains')
insert into #photograph_tags values (8, 'stream')
insert into #photograph_tags values (8, 'mountains')

select * from #photographs
select * from #photograph_tags

select
    p.id
from #photographs p

left join #photograph_tags c
on p.id = c.photograph_id
and c.value IN ('dog', 'water', 'stream')

group by p.id

having count(c.value) >= 3


drop table #photograph_tags
drop table #photographs
```

Comment: This query is displaying some of the same rows multiple times

Comment: and some that don't have all three

Comment: @ThinkingInBits: there you go, updated the sql so the the photo must have all there tags

Comment: empty result set now... I edited the original post with my basic db schema

Comment: @ThinkingInBits: just tested it with your data, works perfectly, check that your not getting you id columns mixed up

Comment: This looks just like how my tables are set up, but I'm not getting any results

Comment: @ThinkingInBits: strange as I am definitely getting a result. maybe there isn't a photo with the 3 specific tags in you database. good luck, i've got to get back to work

Comment: There are two images that contain all three tags and more

Comment: Figured out the problem... had to add having count(c.value) >= 3... Thanks!  I need to brush up on my SQL :D

Comment: @ThinkingInBits: awesome :) updated my answer to include the >=3

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.* FROM photographs p join 
(select id, COUNT(id) as TagCount 
    FROM Photograph_Tags c
    WHERE c.value IN ('dog', 'water', 'stream')
    group by id) 
    as TagCounts on p.id = TagCounts.id
WHERE TagCount = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT p.* 
FROM photographs p
WHERE (c.value IN ('dog', 'water', 'stream'))
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM photograph_tags c
       WHERE c.photograph_id = p.id) >= 3;

will give you photographs with at least three tags.